# Windows event ID 4724 generated for password change

Tags: windows

Per Microsoft documentation, event id 4723 is generated when a user changes their own password using the CTRL-ALT-DELETE secure attention sequence dialog.

However, upon testing in the lab, event id 4724 is generated instead. Event id 4724 should be generated when an administrator performs a *reset* of the password of an account without providing the current password.

Does anyone know the reason?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4723
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4724

Comment: How exactly was the password changed?

Comment: net user * ---> then add the new password

Comment: So, your question ***should*** be: "Is using `net user` considered to be the user "changing it themselves?"

Comment: yeah I assumed this, correct me if I am wrong

Comment: The correction would appear to be self-evident...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way for an end user to change their password is to use the Secure Attention Sequence (SAS), CTRL-ALT-DELETE. When presented with the security dialog, select Change Password. This will prompt the user for their old and new passwords. Other processes perform an administrative reset of the password and do not produce the desired result or event records.